# Azure Webjob failing Exit Code -1073740940

Tags: c#, azure, file-io

I have written a c# console app which I've deployed to an Azure Webjob. The app runs fine locally but on Azure I get the error:

```
[09/16/2015 10:40:35 > 998fb8: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -1073740940
```

I think I've tracked it down to accessing a certificate file. I have added it to a Resources.resx in the project's properties and I'm accessing the cert with the following (also the line it's failing on)

```
X509Certificate2 _certificate = new X509Certificate2(echoService.Properties.Resources.public_privatekey, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certPsw"]);
```

Is this the correct way, or is there a better way. I've tried using a relative path in AppSettings but failed with this as well.

As a side note, I have put the plain text password in AppSettings for now but will handle this better when my concept is proven. Is there a discussion on how to store passwords like this, and whether the certificate should be created without a password?

Comment: Use your programming calculator.  -1073740940 == 0xC0000374 == STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION, "A heap has been corrupted".  Ouch.  The code that trips this exception is almost never the code that caused the corruption.  You'll have to look for blunt weapons of mass destruction used in the rest of your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that Azure copies the files to a temporary location to get around locking of files for a continuous job. Apparently the resource files aren't copied with it.

However for certificates I can reference them using the following tutorial and all is now working
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/

Comment: Chris, do you have a solution for files that aren't certificates?

Comment: @joshuahornby10 not off the top of my head, this problem was only related to the certificate. What files do you need to include/reference?